# Unable to play video Uri when selected from ListView in Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am trying to play back a video uri that has been recorded on a VideoView. The uri of the video when recorded is converted to a string and stored as a string in my database. These strings are then displayed to the user as a ListView, where they can select one from the list. My intention is when a string is selected, the video will play, by converting the string back to a Uri and passing the Uri to the VideoView. However, my app keeps telling me "unable to play video" when I select a video from my list view.

My code is as follows:

```
public class WatchVideo extends Activity {
    VideoView watchVideo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.video_activity);
        watchVideo = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.myvideoView);

        Bundle transferData = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (transferData != null)
        {
             String vidUri= transferData.getString("VideoSelect");
           Uri watchUri = Uri.parse(vidUri);
            watchVideo.setVideoURI(watchUri);
            watchVideo.start();
        }
    }
}
```

Am I converting the string to Uri incorrectly?

Comment: Can you print out the vidUri string?

Comment: Yes, the vidUri string is definitely there. Tested it already. I'm presuming the problem is converting it back to the Uri. If I simply record a video and play it to a VideoView in OnActivityResult, which I have in a different method, then the VideoView has no problem playing the Uri.

Comment: it appear that you just can not put a videoView inside a listView so I did a litle trick, I just put a gridView with just one column and that did the trick

I found that in another question.

Comment: Just put the VideoView into a GridView there, works perfectly. Thanks a million!

Comment: Yes, the answer is accepted, I didn't try it myself.

Comment: Okay now I have another issue. When the database is empty and I record a video, the first video recorded will play once. However, this video will not play a second time, nor will any other videos recorded after the first, unless the database is cleared again.

Comment: You should put the new question into its own question. Also I propose to make an answer to your own question, based on what you learned from comments. Or ask the commenter to, if you want him to have the reputation it might create.